# surfnorm function more efficient way Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

After constructing the point cloud I want to get the normal of each point and I used the built-in matlab function surfnorm but its takes a lot of processing time. So if anyone could assist me do this a better and more efficient way.

Comment: How do you define the normal? Is it "at the center of every triangle"?

Comment: thanks for your comment! I want to compute normals of the surface, I'm using this surfnorm(pcloud(:,:,1),pcloud(:,:,2),pcloud(:,:,3)); but its taking alot of time. Yes, I think if I'd be able to get normals at the center of every triangle this would be very helpful!

Comment: @Floris I'm wondering if you have any suggestions please?

Comment: Although you are talking about a "point cloud", if by chance the points are on an evenly spaced grid, this would greatly simplify things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if the following code would help you. There are three steps here.

1. Create 500 randomly spaced points (x,y), and compute a corresponding value z (the height of the surface) for which I chose a `sinc` like function
2. Resample the random points using the `TriScatteredInterp` function - this permits me to obtain points on an evenly sampled grid that "roughly correspond" to the initial surface
3. Compute the normal to "some points" on that grid (since there are 480x640 points, computing the normal at every point would just create an impossibly dense "forest of vectors"; by sampling "every 10th point" you can actually see what you are doing

The code I used was as follows:

```
randomX = rand(1,500);
randomY = rand(1,500);
r = 5*sqrt(randomX.^2 + randomY.^2);
randomZ = sin(r) ./ r;

% resample the data:
[xx yy] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,640), linspace(0,1,480));
F = TriScatteredInterp(randomX(:), randomY(:), randomZ(:));
zz = F(xx, yy);

%% at each point, the normal is cross product of vectors to neighbors
xyz=reshape([xx yy zz],[size(xx) 3]);
xv = 10:30:479; yv = 10:30:639; % points at which to compute normals
dx = xyz(xv, yv+1, :) - xyz(xv, yv, :);
dy = xyz(xv+1, yv, :) - xyz(xv, yv, :);

normVecs = cross(dx, dy); % here we compute the normals.
normVecs = normVecs ./ repmat(sqrt(sum(normVecs.^2, 3)), [1 1 3]);

figure;
quiver3(xx(xv, yv), yy(xv, yv), zz(xv, yv), ...
    normVecs(:,:,1), normVecs(:,:,2), normVecs(:,:,3));
axis equal
view([56 22]);
```

And the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried this solution using my X Y and Z values found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhlqozajn5typy6/XYZ.mat but the problem the normal is not calcualted for all the points, only the normal of a limited number of points is shown, so if you could please advise

Comment: If you look at my code (and the annotations) I choose to compute the normal at just a few points (the grid given by `xv` and `yv`) because it's easier to see the plotted vectors. If you just make the `xv` and `yv` fully dense (e.g. `1:479` instead of `10:30:479`, etc) it should work.

Comment: I've updated it but its taking a longtime to plot the result. Also the normals are not relevant to the actual image. This is the actual image of the the 3D points I sent in my previous comment, I'm not sure why this is happening https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hqk188hoz2xbmx/data.PNG?m

Comment: Just to clarify, computing the normal is not taking time but the `quiver3` fn is taking time

Comment: This didn't clarify things at all, sorry to say. My code shows how to compute the normal to the surface on a regular grid, starting with an irregularly sampled point cloud. When you actually plot this many points (639 * 479 = 33051 points) it WILL take Matlab a long time, and you will see "nothing useful" in the end. What do you actually want? I thought I had answered your question - apparently I haven't. And what does "the normals are not relevant to the actual image" mean?

Comment: sorry for that! and I'm very thankful for your kind assistance. Actually the computation of the normal is not taking time the plotting is. What I want to do is to have the value of the normal of each pixel in the 640x480 image so that I'll have a result matrix with the same size having the normal of each pixel of the original image.

Comment: Well - you have it in the matrix `normVecs`. The `quiver3` command was there to prove that it worked - but you can just skip that step and use the normals. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes I know, but when you check the input data I gave and compare it to values in `normVecs` but the data is not correct. For example there are a lot of pixels have zero values but you'll find a value of the same pixel index in `normVecs`. Also why the `normVecs` has a less row and col 479x639 instead of 480x640.

Comment: You never said that a zero pixel cannot have a normal... And if you looked at the math used for computing the normal you need your neighbor to the +x and +y direction (three points define a plane). Thus you get stuck at the very edge and will have one fewer normal than pixel. I assumed "you could figure it out from here". Remember SO is not a contract code shop - we are volunteers, helping with advice and suggestions...

Comment: I totally understand your kind assistance, volunteering, advice and suggestions, I really really appreciate this. I'm trying to do everything by myself but sometimes when I need to enhance or look for a more efficient solution I ask here. And again, I'm really thankful for your kind assistance, support and help

Comment: @Floris, I keep coming back to this. I find the simplicity of it really gorgeous, no reliance on any 'black box' tools and answers so many questions about dealing with and fitting to surfaces. Thankyou

Comment: @wentbackward that is very kind!